# Xaml Parse Exception - type mismatch between "Xamarin.Forms.Binding" and "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set/bind a list property in a content view class in xaml.

This is my Class :

```
public class Myclass:ContentView
{
public static readonly BindableProperty TabItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            "TabIndicatorItemSource",
            typeof(IEnumerable<string>),
            typeof(Myclass)
        );

public IEnumerable<string> TabIndicatorItemSource { 
get
{
    return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(TabItemSourceProperty);
}
set
{
    SetValue(TabItemSourceProperty, value);
}
}}
```

and This is my Xaml in ExampleClass.xaml.cs

```
local:Myclass x:Name="myCarouselView" TabTextSizeTabIndicatorItemSource ="{Binding tabListSource}"
```

And tabListSource is a List property in ExampleClass.cs.

However I get this type mismatch error. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindable Properties need to adhere to a set naming convention. e.g. TabItemSourceProperty relates to TabItemSource

```
public class Myclass: ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TabItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            "TabItemSource",
            typeof(IEnumerable<string>),
            typeof(Myclass)
        );

    public IEnumerable<string> TabItemSource { 
        get
        {
             return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(TabItemSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TabItemSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }}
```

with

```
local:Myclass x:Name="myCarouselView" TabItemSource="{Binding tabListSource}"
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't throw the error now. However the set is not getting called. TabItemSource always returns null.